# Problem using android.accounts Authenticator

Tags: android, authentication, accounts

I'm new to the android.accounts apis, and now I'm trying to do something with them but a seemly dummy problem occurs...
I`ve created an Authenticator for my app but did not yet implement the abstract methods. The icon of it successfully appears in the system Add a Account window, and I know that when I click it, the method addAccount in the Authenticator will be invoked.

Now I wish to do some simple thing in this method, and write codes below:

```
    @Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
        String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures,
        Bundle options) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "RRAuthenticator add account... ");
    String accountName = "example@example.com";
    Account account = new Account(accountName, accountType);
    String password = "example_password";
    AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);
    manager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
    bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType);
    bundle.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, "example_authtoken");
    return bundle;
}
```

I've seen the demo of SampleSyncAdapter, and make moves like it. But I practice using these APIs by directly adding an account.
But system crashed by the line `manager.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null);`
What's wrong with it?

---

Added later:
Exception in system process. System will crash.
NullPointerException throw by AccountManager.
It seems the problem of the addAccountExplicitly method, as I comment this statement no crash happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out.

It turns out that it's a bug in Android 2.0.
If you add an account to the AccountManager, you *must* also provide a SynAdapter to the account, under the Android 2.0 platform. But things are all right under Android 2.1 and above.

This is a known issue, please refer to:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5009
and
[AccountManager without a SyncAdapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085242/accountmanager-without-a-syncadapter)

Answer (score 0):

```
 Account account = new Account(username, AuthConstants.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
            if (am.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, null)) {
                result = new Bundle();
                ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, DB.AUTHORITY, true);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
                return result;
            }
```

I am using this code in one of my apps which works perfectly. the key here is the AccountAuthenticatorActivity that should set the authentication result bundle which should be registered (the sync adapter from android developers has this.

also here is my addAccount method for the accountAuthentication service

```
    @Override
public Bundle addAccount(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response,
    String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures,
    Bundle options) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, LoginScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra(LoginScreen.PARAM_AUTHTOKEN_TYPE,
        authTokenType);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE,
        response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Authenticator](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/)

Here is a link i used. this is a good project. i believe it is from the last.fm android app. it also has the source code open on git i believe. so try to compare with that.

**PERMISSIONS**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Thank for your concern, DArkO! I know the way to use a Activity to do the real authentication with user interaction, but here I just wish to practice using these APIs, so I add an account directly. But It failed... :( It seems the problem has sth to do with the addAccountExplicitly method. I`m looking for your reply!

Comment: this sync service is quite new on android and still not properly documented but i believe it is necesery to use the AccountAuthenticatorActivity. you can still use an activity to add an account. (you can make the activity with a transparent theme and finish after the account is added so you dont really need to have a formal login/registration screen). BUT i would first try to find some examples on the web about a proper authenticator with all the methods. Look at my edit for link and more info.

Comment: I`ve tried the AccountAuthenticatorActivity way, and put the trial addAccountExplicitly thing immediately in the onCreate method. But the same crash happened as well. I`ll check up the demo you provided.

Comment: hey how about the manifest? did you add the required permissions?